# A query em SQL fica carregando infinitamente sem executar

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados

Todas as querys funcionam separadamente.

A query Demora uns 3 minutos para executar sem o left join da tabela t4 (ou seja, já demora bastante tempo) mas quando eu coloco o left join da t4, ela fica carregando infinitamente e não executa. Todas as tabelas são grandes, então a dúvida seria se a query está correta só que não carrega por ser muito grande ou tem algo errado fazendo ela ficar em looping.

```
select t1.nCampaignID,t2.tCampaignName as 'Nome da Campanha', t2.tMailerSubject as 'Assunto Email',count(DISTINCT t4.aTargetID) as 'Targets',

(select count(subt.tURLName) from tblObjectType20005_10287 subt where subt.nCampaignID  =  t1.nCampaignID and subt.tURLName <> 'OPTOUT_E-MAIL') as Cliques,
(select count(subt.tURLName) from tblObjectType20005_10287 subt where subt.nCampaignID  =  t1.nCampaignID and subt.tURLName = 'OPTOUT_E-MAIL') as Descadastro,
(select count(subt.STATUS_MSG) from VW_Envio_Email_Detalhado subt where subt.ID_Campanha =  t1.nCampaignID and subt.STATUS_MSG = 'ENVIADO') as Enviado,
(select count(subt.STATUS_MSG) from VW_Envio_Email_Detalhado subt where subt.ID_Campanha =  t1.nCampaignID and subt.STATUS_MSG = 'RESPONDIDO') as Respondido,
(select count(subt.STATUS_MSG) from VW_Envio_Email_Detalhado subt where subt.ID_Campanha =  t1.nCampaignID and subt.STATUS_MSG = 'FALHA') as Falha,
(select count(subt.STATUS_MSG) from VW_Envio_Email_Detalhado subt where subt.ID_Campanha =  t1.nCampaignID and subt.STATUS_MSG = 'ABERTO') as Aberto,
(select count(subt.STATUS_MSG) from VW_Envio_Email_Detalhado subt where subt.ID_Campanha =  t1.nCampaignID and subt.STATUS_MSG = 'NÃO ENTREGUE') as 'Não Entregue'

 from tblCampaignCategory as t1

left join tblObjectType20005_10287 as t2
    on t1.nCampaignID = t2.nCampaignID

left join VW_Envio_Email_Detalhado as t3
    on t1.nCampaignID = t3.ID_Campanha

left join tblCampaignTarget as t4
    on t1.nCampaignID = t4.nCampaignID

where nCategoryId = <<Categoria da Campanha>>
    and (t2.tURLName <> 'OPTOUT_E-MAIL'
    or t2.tURLName = 'OPTOUT_E-MAIL' or t3.STATUS_MSG = 'ENVIADO'
    or t3.STATUS_MSG = 'RESPONDIDO' or t3.STATUS_MSG = 'FALHA'
    or t3.STATUS_MSG = 'ABERTO' or t3.STATUS_MSG = 'NÃO ENTREGUE' )

  group by t1.nCampaignID, t2.tCampaignName, t2.tMailerSubject
```

Comment: tenta remover esse monte de subselect e usa o case/when pra cada um dos itens

Comment: Este monte de 'or' em t3.STATUS_MSG pode virar um 'IN'